# G-suite to Salesforce Attribute mapping

Tags: google-workspace, salesforce

I’m running into an issue while mapping attributes from G-suite to Salesforce.

I’ve setup the following environment:
G-suite for Business &
Salesforce lightning sandbox

SSO (SAML2.0) is setup between the two and G-suite is the identity provider.
User provisioning is enabled and I am able to map basic user information (name/email) from G-suite to Salesforce.

I would like to map more attributes and not just the basic user information and here is where I am stuck. I can’t for the life of me figure out which attributes to map and which values are expected.

I would like to fill ‘User license & Profile

[image: screenshot]

While scooping around in G-suite user provisioning, there is an attribute from which I assume it might have something to do with `User license` called `entitlements`.

[image: screenshot].

Google recommends using the `SAML Name ID attribute mapping` for this, but can’t provide any further information on this issue. 
Salesforce support informs me that this issue is out of scope and sents me to Google for more information.

Any insights on this issue are greatly appreciated.